# Passing swift dictionaries with different value types to same function

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
let dict1 = [String : MyType1]
let dict2 = [String : MyType2]
```

To clarify: `MyType1` and `MyType2` are structs and each dict can only have one valueType.

And I'd like to be able to pass them to the same function:

```
func doSomethingWithDict(dict : [String : AnyObject]) {
   // do something with dict
}
```

But that obviously gives me an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : MyType1]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'
```

Is there a way to fix this, is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure that only a dictionary declared as `[String:MyType1]` or `[String:MyType2]` is passed to your function, I think the best solution is declaring a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
```

and then making `MyType1` and `MyType2` conform to it

```
struct MyType1: MyProtocol { }
struct MyType2: MyProtocol { }
```

Now you can declare a function with a generic type `T` that must conform to `MyProtocol`. Finally you declare the `dict` parameter as `[String:T]`.

```
func doSomethingWithDict<T where T: MyProtocol>(dict: [String: T]) {

    guard let value = dict["key"] else { return }

    switch value {
    case let type1 as MyType1: print(type1)
    case let type2 as MyType2: print(type2)
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

This will guarantee you that the value of the dictionary will be `MyType1` or `MyType2`.

### Update

In a comment below you said you want to pass no longer a dictionary but a value of `MyType1` or `MyType2`.

In this case it does become much easier as we no longer need generics.

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
struct MyType1: MyProtocol { }
struct MyType2: MyProtocol { }

func doSomething(elm: MyProtocol) {
    switch elm {
    case let myType1 as MyType1: print(1)
    case let myType2 as MyType2: print(2)
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics are being abused here (and are unnecessary).  If you want protocol conformance you can simply say `func doSomethingWithDict(dict: [String: MyProtocol]) { ... }`.  And since you have to typecast anyway to check that the value is the type you want (and contained in the dictionary), it's much cleaner to use `Any`.

Comment: @par: Thank you for your suggestion, but it does produce a different behaviour. With the declaration you suggested, you could receive a dictionary containing some values of type `MyType1` and other values of type `MyType2`. Instead the generics used in my answer does force you to pass this `[String:MyType1]` or this `[String:MyType2]`. This is what the OP asked.

Comment: To clarify, the dictionaries will always only have one type, either `MyType1` or `MyType2`. My apologies if this wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: @appzYourLife +1, excellent point, and you are correct assuming type rigidity to this degree is required.  OP's question doesn't rule out the possibility of mixed-value structs so I approached the question from a more permissive point of view.

Comment: So, is it a draw? :)    So I repeat my question (that I swear I posted before, but has disappeared), in the generic example, is `doSomethingWithDict()` a function in `MyProtocol` or in the two structs?

Comment: It's not a draw.  appzYourLife's answer is better if you really want to restrict the possible types you can pass in to exactly dictionaries of either `[String: MyType1]` or `[String: MyType2]` with no mixed values.  If that is the case I recommend you update your question and change the accepted answer to this one.

Comment: Where you put the `doSomethingWithDict()` function is a question of how you want it scoped.  Might be better as a separate SO question than a continuation of the comments.

Comment: Ops... I just found a problem into my `switch` statement... I am fixing it :D

Comment: I get the following warning : `Cast from 'T.Type.Type' to unrelated type '[String : MyType1]' always fails`

Comment: @Koen: yep... I am fixing it

Comment: Can I pass a second parameter to `doSomethingWithDict` ?

Comment: I changed my code slightly to pass `MyType` instead of a dict, so I changed the code to: `func doSomethingWithStruct<T where T: MyProtocol>(item: [T]) {}`; but then I get the same Cast warning as above.

Answer (score 1):

`AnyObject` is for class types.  Rewrite your function as:

```
func doSomethingWithDict(dict: [String: Any]) {
    if let myValue = dict["key"] as? MyType1 { ... }
}
```

Comment: `MyType1` and `MyType2` are different structs that I create to build the dictionaries, so I don't think I can use the declaration that you propose.

Comment: I've edited the answer.  `AnyObject` is only for `class` types.  You need to receive `Any` which will take `struct` types as well as `class` types.

Comment: This solution does allow you to pass a dictionary having a `String`, an `Int` or any other `Type` as value. And this issue could be prevented using generics.

Comment: Again, generics are the wrong tool for the job.  If you find yourself having to typecast a value before you can use it, then that value should simply be something "less specific", which most of the time means `Any`, or `AnyObject`.  Yes, you can use a protocol but writing empty protocols all over the code if you're just going to typecast anyway is a huge waste of effort.

Comment: @par: Please read my reply to your comment under my answer. I explained there why generics are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics, but I don't know what you are going to do inside your method:

```
func doSomethingWithDict<T>(dict : [String : T]) {
   // do something with dict
}
```

and you can call it in this way:

```
 doSomethingWithDict(["string1":1])
 doSomethingWithDict(["string1":"v"])
```

where 1 and v are value with different types (Int/String).
Note: using generics  function is  safer than using AnyObject or somwthing like that.

Comment: This actually won't work, because the compiler will generate two separate `doSomethingWithDict` functions, one for each type `T` you use.  What the question is asking is how to receive dictionaries with `String` keys but an arbitrary value type so it can be received by one function.

Comment: Some time the compiler directly run generic function and sometime duplicate function (see WWDC 2014). The user is asking to use only one function. He ask to write down only one function. He is not asking what compiler or the cpu will do..  I think the generic function can help the user when its input  is composed by 2 dictionaries with two different type. May he doesn't know the use of generics.

Comment: I do actually get an error when I want to access a property of `MyStruct`: `Value of type 'Any' has no member foo`; is this something that can be solved maybe with generics (I've heard of it, but don't know how to use it)?

Comment: OP is asking how to receive a dictionary with different value types in the same function.  You cannot accomplish this with generics.  They are entirely the wrong tool for the job.  Also, you should assume the compiler is making unique copies of the function (whether or not it does underneath the hood) because that way your understanding will be clear that a generic gives you a shorthand way of defining multiple unique functions with unique argument signatures.  Look at it this way and it'll make sense why OP can't do what s/he wants with generics.

Comment: @Koen you have to cast the value you receive as `Any` to the type that has the `foo` member.  `Any` literally means "any thing".  See my answer which tries to convert `dict["key"]` to `MyType1` using `as?`.  You *always* need to cast when you receive something of type `Any` if you wish to use it (vs. just passing it somewhere else).

Comment: Got it! And then I can add another if statement for myType2 (and 3, 4..) ?

Comment: @Koen Yep.  You can also conditionally typecast your values in `switch` statements if you have lots of possible types, see the Swift docs for `case let x as MyType1`...